# go through two np.arrays and delete all values bigger then a defined value in one array

Tags: arrays, numpy

I got the arrays `a` and `b` of the same length. If I go ascending through both arrays parallely, I want to delete every value in both arrays for the every value in array `a` > 0.2.

```
print(a)
[0.01898843 0.02292621 0.02621628 0.02949512 0.03256304 0.03648436
  0.04372925 0.04113532 0.05106076 0.052512   0.04578903 0.05662923
  0.05624261 0.0626851  0.06491405 0.06835764 0.07395112 0.075808
  0.09126322 0.1168302  0.12331931 0.11512589 0.13179135 0.13810872
  0.14401422 0.14512059 0.15058154 0.1600896  0.15490434 0.16916868
  0.15755018 0.16333916 0.17718988 0.16769979 0.18357823 0.17304274
  0.18715775 0.19745513 0.19012131 0.20743668 0.20991725 0.22387453
  0.22907572 0.23116967 0.25244596 0.2550046  0.25958188]]
```

```
print(b)
[0.24469897 0.45153278 0.4513381  0.46295688 0.7054203  0.68534905
 0.24309576 0.92957395 0.25478074 0.23484863 0.68354946 0.26241717
 0.5774168  0.22709402 0.6631634  0.41246122 0.4266638  0.5739711
 0.20643993 0.58073324 0.46782446 1.1465902  0.5842695  0.5990051
 0.4022772  0.9816252  1.0006629  0.25262806 0.61737466 0.2234575
 1.0764375  0.7229736  0.22833306 0.967518   0.25310978 1.5422901
 0.6496138  0.25886557 1.2906564  0.46001527 0.65197116 0.41509193
 0.6179607  0.57257795 0.22474702 0.22528468 0.24215169]
```

Afterwards `a` and `b` should be:

```
a
[0.01898843 0.02292621 0.02621628 0.02949512 0.03256304 0.03648436
  0.04372925 0.04113532 0.05106076 0.052512   0.04578903 0.05662923
  0.05624261 0.0626851  0.06491405 0.06835764 0.07395112 0.075808
  0.09126322 0.1168302  0.12331931 0.11512589 0.13179135 0.13810872
  0.14401422 0.14512059 0.15058154 0.1600896  0.15490434 0.16916868
  0.15755018 0.16333916 0.17718988 0.16769979 0.18357823 0.17304274
  0.18715775 0.19745513 0.19012131]]

b
[0.24469897 0.45153278 0.4513381  0.46295688 0.7054203  0.68534905
 0.24309576 0.92957395 0.25478074 0.23484863 0.68354946 0.26241717
 0.5774168  0.22709402 0.6631634  0.41246122 0.4266638  0.5739711
 0.20643993 0.58073324 0.46782446 1.1465902  0.5842695  0.5990051
 0.4022772  0.9816252  1.0006629  0.25262806 0.61737466 0.2234575
 1.0764375  0.7229736  0.22833306 0.967518   0.25310978 1.5422901
 0.6496138  0.25886557 1.2906564]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
mask = a <= 0.2
a,b = a[mask], b[mask]
```